# Find all numbers $a$ for which the equation $a3^x+3^{-x}=3$ has a unique solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, contest-math, exponential-function

> Find all numbers $a$ for which the equation $a3^x+3^{-x}=3$ has a unique solution $x$.

How should I approach this? I don't really see any good way to start the problem, I've seen a similar problem before and If my memory serves me right they used the discriminant somehow(?)

Comment: Start by writing a quadratic in $y=3^x$.

Comment: Like $f(x)=a3^x +3^{-x}-3$?

Answer (score 2):

$$a\cdot 3^x + \frac{1}{3^x}=3$$
$$\frac{a\cdot 3^{2x} - 3\cdot 3^x + 1}{3^x} = 0$$
$$a\cdot 3^{2x} - 3\cdot 3^x + 1 = 0$$

1. So we have a quadratic equation. If we want a unique solution, the discriminant ($D$) must be equal to 0:
   $$D = 9 - 4a = 0$$
   $$a = \frac{9}{4}$$
2. But this is not the end. The equation has another unique solution if $a \leq 0$.
   If $a \leq 0$, then $D \geq 9$, and we have
   $$y_1 = \frac{3 - \sqrt{D}}{2a}$$
   $$y_2 = \frac{3 + \sqrt{D}}{2a} $$
   so $y_2$ is not a solution (because $3^x$ can't be negative) and we have a unique solution in this case too.
   $$Answer: a \in (-\infty , 0] \cup \left\{\frac{9}{4}\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

We can replace $3^{-x}$ by $t>0$ and the equation reads

$$\frac at+t=3.$$

From this we draw

$$a=t(3-t)$$ which describes a downward parabola through $(0,0)$ and $(3,0)$. This equation has a single positive solution in $t$ when $\color{green}{a<0}$, or a double root at the vertex, $\color{green}{a=\left(\dfrac32\right)^2}$ (indeed $\dfrac32>0$).

[image]

Comment: Your technique is awesome

Comment: @TigranHarutyunyan: it is based on the idea that instead of drawing $x$ from $a$, you can draw $a$ from $x$ and look at the invertibility of the relation. This can be helpful to handle some parametric equations.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Multiply everywhere by $3^x$ to get
$$
a(3^x)^2+1=3\cdot 3^x
$$
With substitution $y=3^x$ and a little rearranging, we get
$$
ay^2-3y+1=0
$$
We are looking for the values of $a$ which gives us a single positive solution. The discriminant helps here, but it won't be the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense! Could you elaborate how did you see the "hidden" quadratic here and came up with the conclusion to multiply by $3^x$?

Comment: @Daniel I saw it because I've seen it many times before. But as a more general pointer, every single $x$ appears as an exponent with base $3$, so $y=3^x$ is a reasonable substitution. If you do the substitution _first_, you get $ay+\frac1y=3$, at which point it's very natural to multiply by $y$. There is no real reason I did it in the order I did, with first multiplying and then substituting; I saw two steps that needed to be done, and which came first was basically random. Maybe it would've been more transparent if done in the order described in this comment...

Answer (score 0):

We have $a=3^{1-x}-3^{-2x}.$

Since $$\left(3^{1-x}-3^{-2x}\right)'=\frac{(2-3^{x+1})\ln3}{3^{2x}},$$ we see that for $x=\log_32-1$ the expression $3^{1-x}-3^{-2x}$ gets a maximal value $\frac{9}{4}.$

Thus, for $a=\frac{9}{4}$ our equation has an unique root.

Also, since $$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(3^{1-x}-3^{-2x}\right)=0$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\left(3^{1-x}-3^{-2x}\right)=-\infty,$$we see that any $a\leq0$ is also valid.

Another way.

For $a=0$ our equation has an unique real root.

Let $a<0$.

Thus, $$a3^{2x}-3\cdot3^x+1=0,$$ which is a quadratic equation of $3^x$ with negative product of roots and since $3^x>0$, we obtain that for any $a<0$ our equation has an unique real root.

If $a>0$, so the discriminant should be non-negative, which gives $a\leq\frac{9}{4},$ which says that for any $0<a<\frac{9}{4}$ our equation has two different real roots.

For $a=\frac{9}{4}$ we obtain that our equation has an unique real root.